# R raster::calc calculating quantile with na.rm = FALSE

Tags: r, na, r-raster, quantile

I use raster::calc to compute quantile for each cell across different layers but I do not understand the behaviour when na.rm = FALSE, like in the example below.

Let's create a sample raster and remove 5 values from random cells.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster::raster(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
r[] <- 1:4

s <- raster::stack(r, r*2, r * 3, r * 4, r * 5)
s[]

set.seed(1)
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[]
```

If I remove NAs, the code below works!

```
fun <- function(x) {quantile(x, probs = 0.50, na.rm = TRUE)}
p <- raster::calc(s, fun)
p[]
```

However, if I want to exclude the cells where there is at least one NA, the code does not work!

```
fun <- function(x) {quantile(x, probs = 0.50, na.rm = FALSE)}
p <- raster::calc(s, fun)
```

I was expecting a vector containing 4 NAs, but the code above throws this error instead:

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

Could anybody help me understand why this happens? And what should I do to get the behaviour I was expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is straightforward, and it may not be related to the raster package. The basic idea is if you apply the `quantile` function to values with any `NA`, the `quantile` function returns an error message.

Considering the following example.

```
# Set na.rm = TRUE
quantile(c(1, NA, 3, 4), probs = 0.50, na.rm = TRUE)

50% 
  3

# Set na.rm = FALSE
quantile(c(1, NA, 3, 4), probs = 0.50, na.rm = FALSE)

Error in quantile.default(c(1, NA, 3, 4), probs = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE) :
   missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

When setting `na.rm = FALSE` the second example just returned an error. This is the same when applying `quantile` to raster. `na.rm` needs to be TRUE.

#### Update

To illustrate how to apply the quantile functions while some cells are `NA`, I modified the example dataset from the OP a little.

```
s <- raster::stack(r, r*2, r * 3, r * 4, r * 5)
s[]

set.seed(1)
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[][sample(1:4, 1), sample(1:5, 1)] <- NA
s[]

     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4 layer.5
[1,]       1       2       3       4      NA
[2,]       2      NA       6       8      10
[3,]       3       6       9      12      NA
[4,]       4       8      12      16      20
```

See the last row, which has no any `NA`.

We can then create a function. This function will return `NA` if there are any `NA` from any layers of a location. Otherwise, it will calculate the quantile.

```
# Design a function
quantile_fun <- function(x, probs = 0.50){
  if (anyNA(x)){
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(quantile(x, probs = probs))
  }
}
```

After that, we can apply this function using `calc`

```
p <- raster::calc(s, quantile_fun) 
p[]
[1] NA NA NA 12
```

Comment: Thanks @ycw! How would you go about writing a function to implement the behaviour I was expecting?

Comment: @Claudia Thanks for your feedback. Please see my update.